# Difficulties in getting data between two strings in bash script

Tags: bash, awk, sed

```
    signature: 
      0000 - 70 59 90 77 3b da 12 b5-94 7d ca 72 77 ee 5d   pY.w;....}.rw.]
      000f - 1f a6 6b 17 60 58 4b a3-09 83 55 f5 58 36 80   ..k.`XK...U.X6.
      001e - 1d b8 40 6e d9 95 77 27-46 4c 87 14 45 9a 67   ..@n..w'FL..E.g
      002d - 75 9c 55 a9 f7 1f e1 6e-f6 a7 21 9f 0a 87 96   u.U....n..!....
      003c - dd 00 02 90 07 e0 e7 2c-c0 a3 bd 3b 8e 19 4a   .......,...;..J
      004b - a5 2f b3 e4 e6 f0 10 f1-01 0f 39 e5 9e 55 31   ./........9..U1
      005a - d8 d8 88 13 b6 81 7a 53-f1 9a 1a f8 f6 6f ef   ......zS.....o.
      0069 - b5 9b 36 19 9e da 8b 09-97 f2 b4 55 c0 42 7a   ..6........U.Bz
      0078 - 27 11 6e aa fb 4d eb 40-                       '.n..M.@
    unsignedAttrs:
```

I have one signature file in which I need to find two strings like in above example "signature" and "unsignedAttrs" are the two words I need the data in between two words with following conditions

1) find the last occurance of string that matches with "signature" means "signature" string is present at last of my file
2) after finding it get the data of that block
3) final output will be

```
  70 59 90 77 3b da 12 b5-94 7d ca 72 77 ee 5d
  1f a6 6b 17 60 58 4b a3-09 83 55 f5 58 36 80
  1d b8 40 6e d9 95 77 27-46 4c 87 14 45 9a 67
  75 9c 55 a9 f7 1f e1 6e-f6 a7 21 9f 0a 87 96
  dd 00 02 90 07 e0 e7 2c-c0 a3 bd 3b 8e 19 4a
  a5 2f b3 e4 e6 f0 10 f1-01 0f 39 e5 9e 55 31
  d8 d8 88 13 b6 81 7a 53-f1 9a 1a f8 f6 6f ef
  b5 9b 36 19 9e da 8b 09-97 f2 b4 55 c0 42 7a
  27 11 6e aa fb 4d eb 40-
```

4) size of the data may vary means there can be more lines then given or

I tried with awk command and got the below output but there are extra characters from last line is causing problem

```
            sed -n "/signature:/,/unsignedAttrs/p" $SIGNED_INFO > signer_signature.txt
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                            echo OK
            else
                            echo FAIL
            fi

            sed '1d; $d' signer_signature.txt > Signer_Signature_cert.txt
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                            echo OK
            else
                            echo FAIL
            fi
            rm -rf signer_signature.txt


awk '{$1=$2=$17=""; print $0}'  Signer_Signature_cert.txt 
  70 59 90 77 3b da 12 b5-94 7d ca 72 77 ee 5d 
  1f a6 6b 17 60 58 4b a3-09 83 55 f5 58 36 80 
  1d b8 40 6e d9 95 77 27-46 4c 87 14 45 9a 67 
  75 9c 55 a9 f7 1f e1 6e-f6 a7 21 9f 0a 87 96 
  dd 00 02 90 07 e0 e7 2c-c0 a3 bd 3b 8e 19 4a 
  a5 2f b3 e4 e6 f0 10 f1-01 0f 39 e5 9e 55 31 
  d8 d8 88 13 b6 81 7a 53-f1 9a 1a f8 f6 6f ef 
  b5 9b 36 19 9e da 8b 09-97 f2 b4 55 c0 42 7a 
  27 11 6e aa fb 4d eb 40- '.n..M.@
```

Please let me know if you have any better way to get the data
If you know any 'sed' or 'awk' command options please let me know

Comment: When you say `find the last occurance of string that matches with "signature"` - that means you actually have multiple signature->unsignedAttrs blocks (and other text?) and want to get the text from within **the last** such block in the file, right? Please clarify in your question and if if so should provide more truly representative sample input and expected output in the question. If you only have one such block then the problem becomes so trivial I can't imagine why you're asking given you know a bit of sed and awk.

Answer (score 2):

Running directly on the "$SIGNED_INFO" file:

```
$ tac file | awk '/signature/{exit} f{$1=$2=$NF=""; print} /unsignedAttrs/{f=1}' | tac
  70 59 90 77 3b da 12 b5-94 7d ca 72 77 ee 5d
  1f a6 6b 17 60 58 4b a3-09 83 55 f5 58 36 80
  1d b8 40 6e d9 95 77 27-46 4c 87 14 45 9a 67
  75 9c 55 a9 f7 1f e1 6e-f6 a7 21 9f 0a 87 96
  dd 00 02 90 07 e0 e7 2c-c0 a3 bd 3b 8e 19 4a
  a5 2f b3 e4 e6 f0 10 f1-01 0f 39 e5 9e 55 31
  d8 d8 88 13 b6 81 7a 53-f1 9a 1a f8 f6 6f ef
  b5 9b 36 19 9e da 8b 09-97 f2 b4 55 c0 42 7a
  27 11 6e aa fb 4d eb 40-
```

or with just awk:

```
$ awk '/unsignedAttrs/{f=0} f{$1=$2=$NF=""; rec = rec $0 ORS} /signature/{f=1; rec=""} END{printf "%s", rec}' file
  70 59 90 77 3b da 12 b5-94 7d ca 72 77 ee 5d
  1f a6 6b 17 60 58 4b a3-09 83 55 f5 58 36 80
  1d b8 40 6e d9 95 77 27-46 4c 87 14 45 9a 67
  75 9c 55 a9 f7 1f e1 6e-f6 a7 21 9f 0a 87 96
  dd 00 02 90 07 e0 e7 2c-c0 a3 bd 3b 8e 19 4a
  a5 2f b3 e4 e6 f0 10 f1-01 0f 39 e5 9e 55 31
  d8 d8 88 13 b6 81 7a 53-f1 9a 1a f8 f6 6f ef
  b5 9b 36 19 9e da 8b 09-97 f2 b4 55 c0 42 7a
  27 11 6e aa fb 4d eb 40-
```

The above is based on my understanding that you have multiple signature blocks in the file, if you only had one then all you'd need would be:

```
$ awk '/unsignedAttrs/{f=0} f{$1=$2=$NF=""; print} /signature/{f=1}' file
  70 59 90 77 3b da 12 b5-94 7d ca 72 77 ee 5d
  1f a6 6b 17 60 58 4b a3-09 83 55 f5 58 36 80
  1d b8 40 6e d9 95 77 27-46 4c 87 14 45 9a 67
  75 9c 55 a9 f7 1f e1 6e-f6 a7 21 9f 0a 87 96
  dd 00 02 90 07 e0 e7 2c-c0 a3 bd 3b 8e 19 4a
  a5 2f b3 e4 e6 f0 10 f1-01 0f 39 e5 9e 55 31
  d8 d8 88 13 b6 81 7a 53-f1 9a 1a f8 f6 6f ef
  b5 9b 36 19 9e da 8b 09-97 f2 b4 55 c0 42 7a
  27 11 6e aa fb 4d eb 40-
```

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```
# cat test | sed -n "/signature:/,/unsignedAttrs/p" | sed '1d;$d' | sed -r 's/.... - //g;s/(.*)   .*/\1/g'
      70 59 90 77 3b da 12 b5-94 7d ca 72 77 ee 5d
      1f a6 6b 17 60 58 4b a3-09 83 55 f5 58 36 80
      1d b8 40 6e d9 95 77 27-46 4c 87 14 45 9a 67
      75 9c 55 a9 f7 1f e1 6e-f6 a7 21 9f 0a 87 96
      dd 00 02 90 07 e0 e7 2c-c0 a3 bd 3b 8e 19 4a
      a5 2f b3 e4 e6 f0 10 f1-01 0f 39 e5 9e 55 31
      d8 d8 88 13 b6 81 7a 53-f1 9a 1a f8 f6 6f ef
      b5 9b 36 19 9e da 8b 09-97 f2 b4 55 c0 42 7a
      27 11 6e aa fb 4d eb 40-
```

Comment: @EdMorton oh true. Have fixed a bit.